# Hibernate Filter Plugin not working in Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, plugins, filter, multi-tenant

I am using Hibernate Filter to enable branch id in every domain which inherits Business Domain....I am included hibernate filter in every domain like

```
static hibernateFilters = {
        branchEnabledFilter(condition: ':branch_id=branch_id', types: 'long', default: true)
}
```

Enabling this hibernate filter by Our Grails filter...like the following..

```
def filters = {
        all(controller:'login', action:'auth',invert:true) {
            before = {
                grailsApplication.getArtefacts("Domain")*.clazz.each{ clazz ->
                    if(clazz.getGenericSuperclass().getName().contains('BusinessDomain')){
                        def filter =  clazz.enableHibernateFilter('branchEnabledFilter')
                        filter.setParameter('branch_id',applicationContext.springSecurityService.principal?.branchId as long)
                    }
                }   
            }
            after = {
                //
            }
        }
}
```

When login first time, I am calling the home controller and then In dashboard page, calling notification controller by link...First time i got error like branch id is not set...But my filter working...but it didnt enable the hibernate filter for this request...But if i modified any code in filter like comment println or uncomment println,that time compiling filter...then everything working fine... Pls tell me what happening here... How to fix this...How to make work in all requests..

Comment: What I find interesting here is that you intercept login/auth that usually only displays the login page and requesting the principal's branch id. In most cases this information wouldn't be known as the users is just about to login. I'd probably hook on the login success and then applied the filters. By the way the filters are session aware or the person that logs in first sets them for all others?

Comment: First of all. Thank you for your reply. In login controller,auth action give login page...Except that action,In  every controller's action...I am requesting branch id...invert true will do that job...i think

Comment: Is this issue resolved? I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly, but I'm doing similar stuff and this is the differences I can tell:

I think you need to have different names for each domain filter, ie: *domainAFilter, domainBFilter* etc.

In the Grails filter I use (short version):

```
import org.grails.plugin.hibernate.filter.DefaultHibernateFiltersHolder;

def hibernateSession = grailsApplication.mainContext.sessionFactory.currentSession
DefaultHibernateFiltersHolder.defaultFilters.each { name ->
  def aFilter = hibernateSession.enableFilter(name)
  aFilter.setParameter('branchId', springSecurityService.principal.branchId)
}
```

I also have an "opposite" Grails filter, in your case *onlyAuth(controller:'login', action:'auth')*, that loops through each filter and disables it but I'm not sure if that is needed.

```
def hibernateSession = grailsApplication.mainContext.sessionFactory.currentSession
DefaultHibernateFiltersHolder.defaultFilters.each { name ->
  hibernateSession.disableFilter(name)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer...Changed filter name in all domains...Still branch id is not set...